# jquery to make select box row drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Table name: NEWS

I am selecting data from table and display in `select box` for drag and drop sorting list with database.
plz suggest me how to make selelct box data drag and drop inside select box.

```
 <form action="add_status_news.php" name="" method="post">
    <select id="" name="Remove_news" size="10" style="width:400px; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; float:left; overflow:auto">
        <?php
            foreach($top_select as $top)
            {                   
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $top["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $top["headline"]; ?></option>  
        <?php }?>       
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please, ***stop using `mysql` functions*** [read the red box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect). The extension is _deprecated_, it is unsafe, no longer being maintained and will be removed in the future. Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` (the `i` stands for _improved_), and use prepared statements. PS: The answer to your question is simple: why would a `li`'s id, or inner html be submitted as being part of a form? Use an `input` field

Comment: i used li bcoz it is my drag and drop sortable list

Comment: It doesn't matter why you used it, what matters is that a `<li>` tag is _not_ a form element. When a form is submitted, `<input>` tags and their values are submitted, along with any `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements that may be present (HTML5 adds some more elements, too). Use a session, a cookie or an `<input type="hidden">` (ordered from safest to least safe)

Comment: but drag and drop not working with select tag i tried many times but doesnot working...

Comment: That's because the JavaScript that makes elements draggable needs to be altered, and/or you need to rethink what you're actually doing. You really don't provide enough info for me to tell you what the problems are

Comment: 1) I only need is to Populate select box from database.2)Then make it drag,Drop And Sortable.3)Remove selected row from select box if need to remove.

Comment: OK, so you need to 1) write code that renders a form, using data from the DB, 2) Write front-end code (JavaScript) that makes the correct elements draggable 3) process the form, and remove selected rows from the DB. Get coding, I'd say

Comment: yes exactly...I need exactly....

Comment: You need to actually get what I'm saying here: This is not a free code-generator. Either you learn about the things you need, try writing them yourself and if your stuck with a specific issue, _then_ you can ask a specific question here